# Trigger AWS Lambda function to scan ECR Repositores

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-ecr

I want to ensure the existing/new ECR repos are automatically enabled for ECR scanning. I have written down lambda function but it gives error while executing. My code:

```
from datetime import datetime

def lambda_handler(event, context):
  print(event)
  repository = event(repository)
  scan_client = boto3.client('ecr')
  response = client.put_image_scanning_configuration(registryId='string',repositoryName='repository',imageScanningConfiguration={'scanOnPush': True})
```

It seems it is unable to recognize the repository. The error has shown as below:

```
Response:
{
  "errorMessage": "local variable 'repository' referenced before assignment",
  "errorType": "UnboundLocalError",
  "stackTrace": [
    [
      "/var/task/index.py",
      7,
      "lambda_handler",
      "repository = event(repository)"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Comment: is `repository = event(repository)` supposed to be a reference to a specific repository name or something? It probably should be `repository = event('repository')` because right now Python is looking for an object called `repository` and not finding one.

Comment: can you provide your event that youre printing? this should be in the lambda logs. event should be a dictionary so you want something like `event['repository']`

Answer (score 0):

sure, the event i have created using CFN script is: 
`CloudWatchTrigger:
    Type: AWS::Events::Rule
    Properties:
      Description: 'Trigger ecr-scanning lambda'
      Name: 'ECR-scanning-lambda-trigger'
      ScheduleExpression: "cron(0 8 * * ? *)"
      Targets:
        - Arn: !GetAtt ECRScanningLambda.Arn
          Id: !Ref AWS::StackName
      EventPattern: !Sub |
        {
          "source": [
            "aws.ecr"
          ],
          "detail-type": [
            "AWS API Call via CloudTrail"
          ],
          "detail": {
            "eventSource": [
              "ecr.amazonaws.com"
            ],
            "eventName": [
              "CreateRepository"
            ]
          }
        }`

and the event logs are created in json format:

`{'version': '0', 'id': '9231de02-71ce-3229-465b-0de35af14c83', 'detail-type': 'AWS API Call via CloudTrail', 'source': 'aws.ecr', 'account': '778784494011', 'time': '2019-11-13T22:50:03Z', 'region': 'us-east-1', 'resources': [], 'detail': {'eventVersion': '1.05', 'userIdentity': {'type': 'AssumedRole', 'principalId': 'AROA3KUZMKG5QPDELUJVP:f2b4e859-fb58-416a-a936-0fd489ed8747', 'arn': 'arn:aws:sts::778784494011:assumed-role/ret-datain-mapping-svc-master-deploy-ExecutionRole-1UDREMWKP0SQB/f2b4e859-fb58-416a-a936-0fd489ed8747', 'accountId': '778784494011', 'accessKeyId': 'ASIAIIJ7YJLEZDBCYTHQ', 'sessionContext': {'sessionIssuer': {'type': 'Role', 'principalId': 'AROA3KUZMKG5QPDELUJVP', 'arn': 'arn:aws:iam::778784494011:role/gbts/wsg-devops/ecs-service/ret-datain-mapping-svc-master-deploy-int/ret-datain-mapping-svc-master-deploy-ExecutionRole-1UDREMWKP0SQB', 'accountId': '778784494011', 'userName': 'ret-datain-mapping-svc-master-deploy-ExecutionRole-1UDREMWKP0SQB'}, 'webIdFederationData': {}, 'attributes': {'mfaAuthenticated': 'false', 'creationDate': '2019-11-13T13:32:20Z'}}, 'invokedBy': 'AWS Internal'}, 'eventTime': '2019-11-13T22:50:03Z', 'eventSource': 'ecr.amazonaws.com', 'eventName': 'BatchGetImage', 'awsRegion': 'us-east-1', 'sourceIPAddress': 'AWS Internal', 'userAgent': 'AWS Internal', 'requestParameters': {'imageIds': [{'imageTag': '5LtgRyzi'}], 'acceptedMediaTypes': ['application/json', 'application/vnd.oci.image.manifest.v1+json', 'application/vnd.oci.image.index.v1+json', 'application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json', 'application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.list.v2+json', 'application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v1+prettyjws'], 'repositoryName': 'ret-datain-mapping-svc-master', 'registryId': '778784494011'}, 'responseElements': None, 'requestID': 'ff3d48b9-e988-41fc-b50a-d89dc19a5a70', 'eventID': '5cb34f61-2933-451a-940b-3d6dcdc60485', 'resources': [{'accountId': '778784494011', 'ARN': 'arn:aws:ecr:us-east-1:778784494011:repository/ret-datain-mapping-svc-master'}], 'eventType': 'AwsApiCall', 'vpcEndpointId': 'vpce-05bef348d7105d0c3'}}`

Comment: based on this above output, i have updated the lambda with following boto3 functionbut gives another error:                                                                     `import boto3
from botocore.config import Config
from datetime import datetime

def lambda_handler(event, context):
  print(event)
  print(event['detail']['requestParameters']['repositoryName'])` but it comes with error: `Response:
{
  "errorMessage": "'detail'",
  "errorType": "KeyError",
  "stackTrace": [
    [
      "/var/task/index.py"`

Comment: I don't think you will have anything to scan for the rule create image, right? Don't you want your rule to trigger on PutImage? Anytime an image is updated then your lambda should trigger